# jQuery selecting a checkbox inside form issue

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a form containing checkboxes and I want to check whether the first is checked by the user:

```
<form id= 'other_langs'>
    <input type= 'checkbox' name= 'yes'> I speak other languages <br>
    <input type= 'checkbox' name= 'no'> I do <b>not</b> speak any other language <br>   
</form>
```

and I have written the jQuery function

```
$('#other_langs').click(function(){
  if(('#other_langs').first().prop('checked') == true){alert('ok');}
});
```

The alert (or whatever) does not appear. I have also tried .is(':checked') and it is the same. I also tried

```
if(('#other_langs input[name="yes"]').prop('checked') == true){alert('ok');}
```

I am using jQuery version 1.9.1 and have tried both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: so what is the error in console ?

Comment: Are you sure radio buttons wouldn't be more approriate for that ?

Comment: It says: Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped.

Comment: @adeneo: you're right. But wouldn't the issue be the same?

Comment: Well, yes and no. Your code still wouldn't work, but as both radios would have the same name, neither would the code in the answers below. Just saying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While doing this :

```
$('#other_langs').first()
```

You are checking if the first `#other_langs` is checked. `#other_langs` is a form, you need to do `.children()`  to get the first children of `#other_langs`.

```
 $('#other_langs').children().first()
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `$` in your second example (*in the first one too, but with wrong approach*) -

```
if($('#other_langs input[name="yes"]').prop('checked') == true){
  alert('ok');
}
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/zKkXp/

You can make your first example work like this -

```
if($('#other_langs input').first().prop('checked') == true){
  alert('ok');
}
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/zKkXp/1/

Comment: you're right, and it works like this. But why doesn't the first code work then?

Comment: @martina You can make the first one work like this `-->` `if($('#other_langs input').first().prop('checked') == true){alert('ok');}`

Comment: Wouldn't `$('#other_langs input[name="yes"]:checked').length` be easier ?

Comment: The other code you provide does not work because I need to put .children() before .first(), see answer from K.A Gagnon above. 
@adeneo: with length I get the number of checked items, but I still need to know which one is checked. Anyway, your advice about using radio buttons may be helpful in this sense.

Comment: Well, there's only one checkbox with the name yes, so selecting that checkbox if it's checked would give the selector length, otherwise the length would be zero, and that would be truthy / falsly and can be used in a condition.

Comment: @martina . the other code i provided does work `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/zKkXp/1/